# What is this character's title after all of the events?

Tags: frozen-ii

At the end of Frozen II, Elsa

> abdicates the throne of Arendelle in favor of her younger sister Anna, who is crowned Queen.

What exactly is her title at this point? Does she

> revert to being a Princess of Arendelle? Does she gain some sort of Northuldran title when she settles among them? Is she instead a full commoner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of this depends on the political system of Arendelle and the social system of the Northuld tribe, which we have very little canon information on.

Looking at the (arguably) best-known kingdom in the Western world, England, we can make some guesses, but we must do so with the full knowledge that they can be completely invalidated by Disney or Pixar at any time.  Disney/Pixar can shape the world of Frozen and its social/political structures as needed to tell their stories.

In 1937 Edward VIII abdicated the throne of England, allowing his brother to take the throne as George VI.  Following this, Edward was given the newly-created Ducy of Windsor and took the title Duke of Windsor.  He notably did not 'revert' to the title of Prince, nor was his new position very high in the line for the throne.  In fact, it is an open question if (having previously abdicated) Edward would have been eligible again.

Using this as a guideline, we can best assume that

> Elsa is no longer in the line of succession for Arendelle

although s/he

> probably has a significant position in the tribal structure of the Northuld tribe

which by nature would be much less strictly-defined.

It should be noted that having an actual title gives someone *de jure* power, while this character would almost certainly have *de facto* power by virtue of their inborn talents, history of titled positions, relatives, etc.

Given that, I doubt they could ever be considered a 'commoner', even if they do not have a noble title.

Comment: Edward abidcated in favour of Albert, who took the regal name  "George VI" (and not Elizabeth) I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The ending of the film's [deluxe novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0736440305) refers to her as ***"the Snow Queen"*** although this may be more of a metaphorical reference than a formal title.

> Elsa and the iced water nokk broke through the line of trees at the edge of the forest and rode across the frozen sea, heading toward the horizon.
>
> **The Snow Queen turned her face to the sky and smiled.** Elsa was exactly where she was meant to be, totally free and in her element.